# how to create a batch file that executes a single command on all the files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

how to create a batch file that executes a single command on all the files in a directory

For Example,  directory C;\Test  contains 30 files with an .ini extension. I could run each file individually by using the command  Trade abc.ini, bcd.ini, cde.ini ..... and so forth.
I would like to have a batch file to run the trade command on all the files in the directory without having to name each file individually. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> how to create a batch file that executes a single command on all the files in a directory

```
for %%f in (*.ini) do call echo %%f
```

And replace "echo" with your own command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forfiles` to do that

```
FORFILES /M *.ini /C "cmd /c Trade @file"
```